# JSONException: No value for when value exists

Tags: android, json, getstring, jsonexception

I'm looping through a JSON Array with the intention saving the details to a database.

When I get to the following bit of JSON:

```
{"custom":"0","is_affected":"1","title":"Up Goods","direction":"","affect_type":"O","code":"0","speed":""}
```

I receive following exception message:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for direction
```

The code I am using to is here:

```
public static final String KEY_CUSTOM = "custom";
public static final String KEY_IS_AFFECTED = "is_affected";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_DIRECTION = "direction";
public static final String KEY_AFFECT_TYPE = "affect_type";
public static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
public static final String KEY_SPEED = "speed";

public void saveRT9909(Context context, JSONObject object){
    try{
        String html = object.getString("response");
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(html);
        String action = jObj.getString("action");
        String response = jObj.getString("response");
        JSONObject resp = new JSONObject(response);

        String rt9909 = resp.getString("DataPackRt9909");

        JSONObject rt = new JSONObject(rt9909);

        String pack_id = rt.getString(DB.KEY_PACK_ID);

        String site_wardens = rt.getString(DB.KEY_SITE_WARDENS);

        String declarations = rt.getString(DB.KEY_DECLARATIONS);

        String[][] rt9909Values = {
                {DB.KEYLOWERID, rt.getString(DB.KEYLOWERID)},
                {DB.KEY_PACK_ID, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PACK_ID)},
                {DB.KEY_FORM_INDEX, rt.getString(DB.KEY_FORM_INDEX)},
                {DB.KEY_COSS_NAME, rt.getString(DB.KEY_COSS_NAME)},
                {DB.KEY_NAME_OF_COSS, rt.getString(DB.KEY_NAME_OF_COSS)},
                {DB.KEY_COSS_ID, rt.getString(DB.KEY_COSS_ID)},
                {DB.KEY_SENTINEL_CARD_NO, rt.getString(DB.KEY_SENTINEL_CARD_NO)},
                {DB.KEY_PLANNED_START_TIME, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PLANNED_START_TIME)},
                {DB.KEY_PLANNED_END_TIME, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PLANNED_END_TIME)},
                {DB.KEY_ACTUAL_START_TIME, rt.getString(DB.KEY_ACTUAL_START_TIME)},
                {DB.KEY_ACTUAL_END_TIME, rt.getString(DB.KEY_ACTUAL_END_TIME)},
                {DB.KEY_PERMIT_TO_WORK, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PERMIT_TO_WORK)},
                {DB.KEY_PLANNED_WALKING, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PLANNED_WALKING_ACTUAL)},
                {DB.KEY_PLANNED_WORK, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PLANNED_WORK)},
                {DB.KEY_PLANNED_WORK_ACTUAL, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PLANNED_WORK_ACTUAL)},
                {DB.KEY_TYPE_OF_FENCE, rt.getString(DB.KEY_TYPE_OF_FENCE)},
                {DB.KEY_DISTANCE_FROM_LINE, rt.getString(DB.KEY_DISTANCE_FROM_LINE)},
                {DB.KEY_SEPARATION_DISTANCE, rt.getString(DB.KEY_SEPARATION_DISTANCE)},
                {DB.KEY_COSS_SITE_WARNING, rt.getString(DB.KEY_COSS_SITE_WARNING)},
                {DB.KEY_SITE_WARDEN_WARNING, rt.getString(DB.KEY_SITE_WARDEN_WARNING)},
                {DB.KEY_RED_ZONE_WARNING, rt.getString(DB.KEY_RED_ZONE_WARNING)},
                {DB.KEY_SAFETY_LOCATIONS, rt.getString(DB.KEY_SAFETY_LOCATIONS)},
                {DB.KEY_ACCESS_EGRESS, rt.getString(DB.KEY_ACCESS_EGRESS)},
                {DB.KEY_HAZARDS_SITE, rt.getString(DB.KEY_HAZARDS_SITE)},
                {DB.KEY_ADDITIONAL_INFO, rt.getString(DB.KEY_ADDITIONAL_INFO)},
                {DB.KEY_LIMITS_DEFINITION, rt.getString(DB.KEY_LIMITS_DEFINITION)},
                {DB.KEY_ADD_SIGHTING_CHARTS, rt.getString(DB.KEY_ADD_SIGHTING_CHARTS)},
                {DB.KEY_PACK_SITE_LOCATION_CUSTOM, rt.getString(DB.KEY_PACK_SITE_LOCATION_CUSTOM)},
                {DB.KEY_COSS_SIGNATURE_ID, rt.getString(DB.KEY_COSS_SIGNATURE_ID)},
                {DB.KEY_NEAREST_LINE_CODE, rt.getString(DB.KEY_NEAREST_LINE_CODE)},
                {DB.KEY_CHANGE_REASON, rt.getString(DB.KEY_CHANGE_MANAGER)},
                {DB.KEY_CHANGE_AUTHORITY_NO, rt.getString(DB.KEY_CHANGE_AUTHORITY_NO)}
        };


        String pack_linesAff = rt.getString(DB.KEY_PACK_LINES_AFFECTED);

        JSONArray plaArr = new JSONArray(pack_linesAff);


        for (int n =0; n < plaArr.length(); n++){
            JSONObject pla = plaArr.getJSONObject(n);

            String[][] plaValues = {
                    {DB.KEY_PACK_ID, pack_id},
                    {DB.KEY_CUSTOM, pla.getString(DB.KEY_CUSTOM)},
                    {DB.KEY_IS_AFFECTED, pla.getString(DB.KEY_IS_AFFECTED)},
                    {DB.KEY_TITLE, pla.getString(DB.KEY_TITLE)},
                    {DB.KEY_DIRECTION, pla.getString(DB.KEY_DIRECTION)},
                    {DB.KEY_AFFECT_TYPE, pla.getString(DB.KEY_AFFECT_TYPE)},
                    {DB.KEY_CODE, pla.getString(DB.KEY_CODE)},
                    {DB.KEY_SPEED, pla.getString(DB.KEY_SPEED)}
            };

            Log.d("RT9909", pla+"");
        }



    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Furthermore if I hardcode a value for direction then I get the same exception regarding affect_type.

**JSON Response**
[image]

Comment: Can you put full your json content?

Comment: Updated with the full JSON response and more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `rt.getString(key)` to `rt.optString(key)`

Comment: Would be good to just mention that it returns empty string if empty/null

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `JSONObject.getString` function is looking for the value of the key in the key-value-pair when it's interpreting the string, and throwing an exception if it doesn't find one.

Use the `JSONObject.isNull()` function to check whether the value in the key-value-pair exists before mapping it to your array. See below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Also note it mentions that the getString function will throw an exception if the value cant be found.

edit: `JSONObject.isNull` rather than JSONObject.has

Comment: Just to add, check out: optString(String name). This seems like its what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Some your json objects are missing fields. 
For example

Your correct json object

```
{"custom":"0","is_affected":"1","title":"Up Goods","direction":"","affect_type":"O","code":"0","speed":""}
```

Your json object is missing fields:

```
{"custom":"0","is_affected":"1","title":"Up Goods"}
```

So when you call jsonObject.getString("direction") will throw Exception.

You can safer check the instance/existing of your field before get it.

For example

```
private String optString(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
    return jsonObject.isNull(key) ? null : jsonObject.optString(key);
}
```